# Error: NG0900: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed, using observable and subcribe

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

So I am trying to get data from the api and send it to a component to use in a table but I keep running into the same problem. I can see that the data is there but there is some problem. This is a snipit from my console.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4RNc.png)

From the service

```
  public getProjects(): Observable<Project[]>{
        return this.http.get<CustomResponse>(`${this.apiUrl}/project/list`)
      .pipe(map(data => data.data )     ***//changed to data.data.projects***
      )
  }
```

From the component

```
    ngOnInit(){ 
      //                        | curser for the error is in between . and s line 24
      this.service.getProjects().subscribe((value: Project[])=>{
        this.projects= value;
        console.log(value);             //line 26
        console.log( typeof(value));    //line 27
        console.log(this.projects);     //line 28
      })
```

Custom Response Interface

```
export interface CustomResponse {
    timeStamp: Date;
    statusCode: number;
    status: string;
    reason: string;
    message: string;
    developerMessage: string;
    data:  Project[];          ***// changed to data:any***
}
```

Project interface

```
export interface Project{
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

I have tried many things such as changing the way I map and pipe, and even changing the whole way that I actually write the function but I just do not understand the problem. I have tried what I have seen online but nothing helps. I'm just hoping someone knows why this is happening.

UPDATE:
You guy were right, the api was returning an object that contained an array. In my custom response interface I had data: Project[], which was false. When I tried to access the projects array that was in data I would get an error. Instead I just changed data: any, and I was able to return data.data.projects which worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your typing doesn't match API response. You have

```
interface CustomResponse {
//...
    data:  Project[];
}
```

but what actually comes is

```
{
//...
    data: {
        project: {
            projects: Project[]
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the map in getProjects() to

```
map(data => data.data.projects)
```

and it should work.

Comment: Where is the `project` key? I think it should be `projects: Project[]` directly under data.

Comment: @ShamPooSham maybe it should, but the `console.log`s indicate that what comes from `getProjects` is an object containing an array.

Comment: What I mean is that what you posted as "what actually comes is" doesn't match what the console log says. It's one level too deep

Answer (score 0):

You guy were right, the api was returning an object that contained an array. In my custom response interface I had data: Project[], which was false. When I tried to access the projects array that was in data I would get an error. Instead I just changed data: any, and I was able to return data.data.projects which worked